# How can I use variables from bash in the curl command on Jenkins instance?

Tags: python, json, bash, jenkins, curl

I trigger python script in bash shell.The results of python script is number. I need this number as variable in bash and I want to use it to url in curl command.

Here are exemplary data but I want to explain what I mean:

```
POST=$(python3 /repo/post.py)
echo "${POST}"
echo "curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json""
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"
```

output:

```
30
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
<h1>Server error</h1>
<p>An unspecified error occured.</p>
```

But when I write manually this number I mean:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
```

I get right output.

I wonder because I run this curl command on Jenkins where whole script is writing in the bash. But this python script which I trigger, it uses json file which obtained from earlier command curl, for example

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" -H "Version: {$VERSION}" -T "post.tar.gz" "https://wikipedia.org/api/upload/" >file.json
```

And if I trigger Jenkins job using my repo (where file.json is saved on my repo) this curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"
```

is working but if I use this file.json from Jenkins workspace then this curl command is not working. I will only mention that this Jenkins job is not pipeline. I guess it is multi-configuration project or freestyle project.

python script which is not working on Jenkins:

```
import json
import os

WORKSPACE = os.environ.get('WORKSPACE')
json_text = str()
with open(f'{WORKSPACE}/file.json', 'r') as f:
    json_text = f.read()

data = json.loads(json_text)

post = data['POST']

print (post)
```

python which is working on Jenkins:

```
import json
import os

json_text = str()
with open('repo/marta/file.json', 'r') as f:
    json_text = f.read()

data = json.loads(json_text)

post = data['POST']

print (post)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this without jenkins?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why would you want to use `curl` instead of using Python `requests`?

Comment: I mean can you repeat this error on your computer with only curl, bash and python? Is jenkins required to reproduce the error you're seeing?